# Нужно написать функцию, которая бы вычисляла сумму ряда 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8.....с заданной точностью

Tags: c++, функции, математика

Всех приветствую.
Есть задача: написать функцию, которая бы вычисляла сумму ряда 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 ..... с заданной точностью.
Прежде всего хочу сказать, что пошел на курсы совсем недавно. Никакой базы и каких-то знаний математики не имеются. Поэтому тяжело понять вообще с чего начинать писать функцию и куда двигаться.
Направьте пожалуйста, или напишите пример кода решения задачи.. Хочу понять как решить правильно простейшим возможным способом (максимум используя один из циклов), без использования каких-либо массивов и тд. Всем спасибо за любую помощь!

Comment: Почитайте про сумму членов бесконечно убывающей геометрической прогрессии

Answer (score 3):

> 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + ...
>
> Хочу понять как решить правильно простейшим возможным способом
> (максимум используя один из циклов), без использования каких-либо
> массивов и тд. Всем спасибо за любую помощь!

```
double calc_seq()
{
    return 1;
}
```

Ну и общий ход мыслей :)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как говорится, продолжите дальше по аналогии

Comment: ROFL!!!!!!!11111

Comment: А не должно быть `return 1.0` ?

Comment: @Alexey Ten, так автоматом же переведется

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy, подсчитать до какого-то члена? тогда сумма геометрической убывающей прогрессии `s = (1 - pow(0.5, n))` (алгебра 9 класс вроде), чуть сложнее подсчитать до куда можно вообще вычислять эту последовательность для `float` к примеру - тут уже логарифм брать придется :)

Comment: @StanislavVolodarski формально это решение верно для любого eps. По определению, разница между точным ответом и приближённым должна быть меньше eps — это условие очевидно выполняется

Answer (score 2):

С точностью `eps`?

```
double sum()
{
    return 1.0 - eps;
}
```

Для тех, у кого плохо с чувством юмора:

```
return 1 - exp(-log(2)*ceil(-log(eps)/log(2)));
```

Но "с точностью ε" - это значит, отличающееся от истинного *не более* чем на ε, так что 1 - вполне удовлетворяет этому условию, как и 1-ε...

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Что-то у вас к вечеру с чувством юмора не то... Понимаете, ответы 1. формально верны, но при этом 2. не помогают халявщику, который ни строчки не написал сам - в отличие от вашего ответа...

Answer (score 0):

Что обычно требуется чтобы вычислить частичную сумму ряда с заданной точностью?

Сама точность: `eps`. Точностью пользуются так: складывают члены ряда пока очередной член не станет меньше `eps`.

Способ для вычисления очередного члена ряда. Первый член равен `1/2`. Следующий в два раза меньше. Следующий за ним ещё в два раза меньше. И так далее. Оператор чтобы перейти от текущего члена к следующему: `a = a / 2`.

Еще будет нужна переменная для суммы: `s`.

Псевдокод:

```
eps = ...
a = 1.0 / 2.0    # первый член ряда
s = 0.0          # сумма стартует всегда с нуля
while a >= eps:   # складываем пока на достигнута нужная точность
    s = s + a    # добавляем новый член в сумму
    a = a / 2.0  # вычисляем следующий член

# s - содержит нужную сумму
```

Замечание по поводу применения `eps`. То что мы суммируем до `a < eps`, не означает что мы приблизились к сумме бесконечного ряда на расстояние `eps`. Для данного конкретного ряда разница между конечной суммой и бесконечной может достигать `2 * eps`. Для других рядов будут другие соотношения. Никаких общих оценок дать нельзя.

Comment: вы так недовольны другими ответами, но при этом не проверили свой же :) что будет результом вашего псевдокода если точность 1/2? И предупреждая исправление ```a>eps``` на ```a>=eps```, теперь проверьте для ```eps=0.6```

Comment: Ряды суммируются до достижения точности члена. Точность суммы может отличаться как угодно сильно. В данном случае в два раза. Дефект метода, который не исправить простыми методами.

Comment: За упоминание случая равенства спасибо. Поправил.

Comment: "Ряды суммируются до достижения точности члена." мне вот интересно, с чего вы это взяли? В вопросе сказано вычислить сумму с заданной точностью, ваш метод НЕ вычисляет с заданной точностью. "Точность суммы может отличаться как угодно сильно." что за ерунда? это даже не соответсвует ТЗ

Comment: @timbars, мой подход имеет недостатки, которые я указал. Ваш подход требует аналитической оценки скорости сходимости ряда. Это мало похоже на учебное задание по программированию. Просуммируйте `sin(k)/k` с заданной точностью, например.